# How to convert one string to many values then use formulas?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

As the script, I want to get "setFormulas" work

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
var s1r = ss.getSheetByName("sheet1").getRange("D5:K28")
var s2r = ss.getSheetByName("sheet2").getRange("D5:K28")
var s0rv = ss.getSheetByName("sheet0").getRange("D5:K28").getValues()

    s1r.setFormulas("=IFERROR(sheet2!" + s0rv + ")")
    s2r.setFormulas("=IFERROR(sheet1!" + s0rv + ")")
```

with this script how to do we "=IFERROR(sheet#!" + ... + ")" convert to be same string as many values

...setFormulas(...getValues()) I believe, it work just fine. But if we work with a singular string, is it possible?

I'm sorry for an unclear question, more than that I just realized the out come still error (#REF) anyways it could be fine for me. and

getvalues() from

[image: Get values from Sheet0]
I just wanna set the formulas to be like this

[image: Want to get the result like this, sheet 1]
[image: Want to get the result like this, sheet 2]

Comment: Your question is unclear. Please include screenshots to show **input** and **expected output**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Array.map` to spread out the values and change formula:

```js
s1r.setFormulas(s0rv.map(row => row.map(ref => ref ? "=IFERROR(sheet2!" + ref + ")" : null )));
s2r.setFormulas(s0rv.map(row => row.map(ref => ref ? "=IFERROR(sheet1!" + ref + ")" : null )))
```

Comment: It works. I'm sorry for the late check the correct answer. I've just checked out one of my undone-yet projects. I can learn the amazing code from this. Thanks a lot